# asp.net mvc5 SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, signalr

this question(s) is nothing really about my code. It's about understanding how I should do a certain thing.

**Question 1:**

I'm working on a fun little project that will send some info from a WPF client to a WebSite. But what I want to do is, I want to be available to login onto my WPF client and send that to a user.

So, let's say I login as "TestUser1" on my WPF Client I want signalR to send his Info to that user on the website. So when he login to that user on the asp.net mvc5 I want him to get that information and no one else.

**Question 2:**

So if he would log in as "TestUser2" He would not get anything since it's sending the info to "TestUser1". Would this be possible with SiglaR?

And to my other question, which is more or less a follow up. As I want the WPF client to send info the website, Should I make the WPF Client the server aswell, or Should I make 1 WPF client, and than 1 WPF servers that both the website and the clients connect to.

Or would it be possible to make the Client Both the server and the Client?

Comment: You should really look into SignalR before asking this, as it's a bit too broad for now. It is definitely possible, and I think SignalR would be a good technology to choose for this, search for 'chat tutorial signalr c#' and you're guaranteed a large number of relevant articles explaining how to 'send info' and target particular users/connections.

Comment: I've made a SignalR Chat already, with a WPF client, WPF server and a website, how ever. I just didn't know if it would be smart to make the WPF Client both the client and the server. Nor how I would send info to a certin user. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client should not be server. You need a host for your SignalR server (For example your existing Webserver).

THen use pub/sub pattern to subscribe to the username on the website and then publish on the client. SignalR does not support pub/sub out of the box, either roll your own or use a library, I have created this library which I think would suit your needs perfect.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Here is a little demo how you can publish and subscribe to all SignalR connection states.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/ConnectionStateExample/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

It broadcasts all connection states for all users to all users, but using the built in constraint API of my library it should be easy to implement

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki/Implement-constraint-handlers

Here is a live demo:
http://malmgrens.org/signalR/